# Meteor throws "Must throw non-empty error" on page load

Tags: meteor

So my Meteor project just crashes after a small ammount of time (2 seconds (maybe)). I get this error in the console and Meteor exits: (whole console output from `meteor` command)

```
[[[[[ /path/to/meteor/project ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/

/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.42pmuo++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:259
            throw new Error('Must throw non-empty error');
                  ^
Error: Must throw non-empty error
    at Object.Future.throw (/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.42pmuo++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:259:10)
    at Extract.<anonymous> (/tools/fs/files.js:699:42)
    at Extract.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at DirWriter.<anonymous> (/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.42pmuo++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/tar/lib/extract.js:61:8)
    at DirWriter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at FileWriter.<anonymous> (/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.42pmuo++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:158:12)
    at FileWriter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.42pmuo++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/file-writer.js:50:47)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:239:10)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:257:5)
    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:97:5)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1692:14
    at Object.wrapper [as oncomplete] (evalmachine.<anonymous>:522:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be an issue with available free space, or an error handling bug? This issue reports a similar case: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4178

Comment: Okay. Thats weird. I got like 300 MB of free space available. When I start my Meteor project they drain quite fast. When I'm about to hit 0 meteor crahses. But why does it do tha?. My project is on another disk.

Comment: @Le'nton In order to actually serve your project, Meteor needs to download a bunch of dependencies that can easily surpass 300 MB.

Comment: I just removed old kernels. It needed 500 MB.  now it works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not enought space for mongo.
Try to install mongo and then start its server with --smallfiles
Then tell meteor to start using the listening mongo.

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017 meteor
```